# Compiling z3 ocaml binding in linux

Tags: z3

I am trying to compile the OCaml binding for z3 in Linux.

I tried using the provided Makefile: I did "make ocamlrelease" but it aborts with the error
cp: cannot stat `ml_release/build-lib.sh': No such file or directory

I also read the included readme.txt in the ml directory and it says to use SLAM and SDT, but these seem to work only in Windows, not Linux.

How can I compile the OCaml binding?

Thanks,
José

Answer (score 1):

We are currently working on this issue. It should be fixed soon. Right now, the ML bindings available at http://z3.codeplex.com do not work. There are some broken references and Windows only dependencies. This will be fixed.