# Z3: OCaml support in Linux

Tags: z3

The [uploaded nightly builds for Linux](http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/101913) do not include the OCaml bindings. Do we know if the bindings will be added in the future?

Is building from source the only way to get OCaml support? From a previous question ([Compiling z3 ocaml binding in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784686/compiling-z3-ocaml-binding-in-linux)) it seemed that the building system was not ready yet for Linux. Has that changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will soon have a new OCaml API for Z3, and binaries will be included in the nightly builds.
The current OCaml API in the official release is old and does not support new features available in Z3. The new OCaml API will have the same capabilities of the .NET, Java and Python APIs. 
The `ml-ng` [branch](http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?branch=ml-ng) is the working branch for this new API.

Comment: Thank you Leonardo! We can't wait for the OCaml release of your excellent tool.